# VB Datagridview cellvalidating event to check if active cell is empty berore leaving problems

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

In Visual basic i'm trying to make a field required by preventing the user to leave the active cell if it's empty.

The grid consists out of two columns. The first one is the ID which is automaticly filled in on adding a new row, the second one is the name.

On form load there are 4 items loaded into the grid. When the form is loaded the first cell that is selected passes the check with no problem. It is the same for the three cells that are filled on form load.

Unforunately it does not seem to work when i try to add a new row to the grid, enter a value and try to leave the cell. I've set a break point and checked the values. The value is equal to nothing... This is not the case with any of the already loaded values.

How does it not get the value i enter?

Thanks in advance.

Ivan.f

```
    Private Sub ValidateCellValue(sender As Object, e As    
    DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) 
    Handles grdResult.CellValidating
        Dim catNaam = grdResult.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value
        If IsNothing(catNaam) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Veld mag niet leeg zijn")
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: You should probably only validate the cell you're in, so use `.Cells(e.ColumnIndex)`  instead of `.Cells(1)`.  The value hasn't been written yet, so try using the `e.FormattedValue` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 

This solved the problem